# In Emacs, how to automatically enable a minor mode based on buffer name?

Tags: emacs

I have a Emacs extension that creates a buffer named `*erl-output*`. This buffer gets created with only `fundamental-mode` by default. Is there any way to automatically enable `compilation-minor-mode` on that buffer?

Comment: I looked at `compile.el` but didn't find anything useful there.

Comment: Why do you want `compilation-minor-mode`?  Why not the major mode?

Comment: It's just that my extension says something along the lines of `"Enable compilation-minor-mode to be able to click the links"`. I'll take a look at just using `compilation-mode`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To automatically change major modes you can add the following to your .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("^\\*erl-output\\*$" . my-major-mode))
```

This won't work for you; it's for *major* mode selection and you're after *minor* mode selection.

Instead you could try a [Hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html).  The manual says:

> A hook is a Lisp variable which holds a list of functions, to be called on some well-defined occasion.

So you should be able to write a function which sets the minor mode when required.  Looking at the [List of Standard Hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html) I think you should be trying [`temp-buffer-setup-hook` or `temp-buffer-show-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Temporary-Displays.html#Temporary-Displays).

You'll have to write a function which checks the buffer name and sets the mode if required, and add it to the hook using something like the following in your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'temp-buffer-setup-hook 'my-func-to-set-mode)
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem I have. :-)

Comment: @Adam - I've updated my answer to cover Hooks as well as auto-mode-alist; hopefully they'll work for you.

Comment: I tried enabling the major mode with no success. In .emacs I put:
`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("^\\*erl-output\\*$" . compilation-mode))`

It is not created with `compilation-mode`. If I manually create a buffer with `(get-buffer-create "*erl-output*") the mode still doesn't get set

Comment: Did get it to work finally, but I have to maintain patches against the original package. I've notified the authors as to include them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Name patterns in `auto-mode-alist` are applied to file names, not buffer names. So even if a major mode were required here, the proposed solution would not help.

Answer (score 4):

Since your extension is creating the buffer, why not just add:

```
(compilation-mode)
```

(or `(compilation-minor-mode)` if you're really set on the minor mode idea) in the code that's creating the `*erl-output*` buffer.  You can edit the source for the mode, or use advice around the creation routine...

Comment: `compilation-mode` seems to make the buffer read only. The extension writes to the buffer occasionally.